# OSMOSIS syntax for extracting buildings out of country.pbf via .polyfile

Tags: extract, osmosis, pbf

I am new to osmosis and osmfilter did not work with my .poly file. I do not get the syntax working. I like to extract all buildings within a poly file.

I tried just for all objects

`C:\Program Files (x86)\osmosis\bin>osmosis --read-pbf file="C:\Users\User\PowerFolders\Masterarbeit\QGIS Data\Projekte\Deutschland\germany_01.pbf"--bounding-polygon file="C:\Users\User\PowerFolders\Masterarbeit\QGIS Data\Projekte\Deutschland\buffer.poly" --write-xml file="C:\Users\User\PowerFolders\Masterarbeit\QGIS Data\Projekte\Deutschland\all.osm"`

But even this did not work. How to fix this?

failure message below:

[image]